# MongoDb groupping with grouped All data

Tags: mongodb

I need to group my feeds. If UserId and Type equal and in 10 minutes(CreatedOnUtc) group this rows. And Return newest row and Add a new object to GroupedItems and All grouped items must in this object.

```
{ "_id" : 1, “userId" : 212, “type": 10, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:01:08.580" }
{ "_id" : 2, “userId" : 212, “type": 10, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:05:08.580” }
{ "_id" : 3, “userId" : 212, “type": 20, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:06:08.580” }
```

Should return:

```
{ 
"_id" : 2, “userId" : 212, “type": 10, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:05:08.580”,
        GroupedItems:[
        { "_id" : 1, “userId" : 212, “type": 10, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:01:08.580" },
        { "_id" : 2, “userId" : 212, “type": 10, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:05:08.580” }] 
}
{ "_id" : 3, “userId" : 212, “type": 20, “CreatedOnUtc” : “2023-06-08 11:06:08.580” }
```

How could i group this?

Comment: Try `{$group: {_id: "$type", GroupedItems: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}}`

Comment: Thank you, I need to 10 minutes interval for groupping.

Answer (score 0):

For me the output does not make much sense, however you could do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            type: "$type",
            CreatedOnUtc: {
               $dateTrunc: {
                  date: "$CreatedOnUtc",
                  unit: "minute",
                  binSize: 10
               }
            }
         },
         GroupedItems: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceWith: {
         $mergeObjects: [
            { $last: "$GroupedItems" },
            { GroupedItems: "$GroupedItems" }]
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ha8Q14gCh9k)